# Resolving MSBuild Warning MS0109

Tags: c#, ios, msbuild

I'm trying to resolve a large number of warnings that have built up in a Xamarin Forms project I've been tasked with working on. When building the iOS version, I am receiving several warnings that look like the below:

"/Users/redacted/Development/redacted/redacted/Mobile/redacted/MTOUCH: Warning MT0109: The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.dll' was loaded from a different path than the provided path (provided path: /Users/redacted/.nuget/packages/system.io.compression/4.3.0/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard1.3/System.IO.Compression.dll, actual path: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.16/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.IO.Compression.dll). (MT0109) (Itx.iOS)"

I've pretty much combed all over the place for a solution to this problem, but I haven't found much of anything for this issue.

How can I get this stubborn warning to go away?

Comment: It's just a warning and it sounds like the dll is being loaded from somewhere. Wouldn't expect it to lead to any problems, I'd just recommend doing some additional testing on the iOS version. When building for different platforms it's probably to be expected that the library will be loaded from a different path. See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11451/android-system-io-compression-dll-not-available-on-windows